# How to test if a sequence starts with values in another sequence?

Tags: python

How to simply test, if a sequence starts with certain values in Python3?

There's of course the solution of writing a custom function, example below. But **does Python itself offer some solution?** Something more pythonic, an understandable one-liner would be good.

---

```
def startswith(sequence, prefix):
    """return true if sequence starts with items in prefix"""
    if len(prefix) > len(sequence):
        return False
    for i in range(len(prefix)):
        if sequence[i] != prefix[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Is it a `list` or a `tuple`?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
len(prefix) <= len(sequence) and all(i==j for i, j in zip(prefix, sequence))
```